# Get and then join all combinations of rows with strings and integers in Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, combinations

I have an Excel sheet with 3 rows and 5 columns that I want to get all possible combinations of into one row for every combination. Using `itertools` gets all the combinations, but joining them into one row for each result and with different variables is too hard for me.

```
Type    Sort    Length  Width   Weight
Small   P1      4       1.3     11
Medium  P2      2       1.6     4
Large   P3      7       1.1     8
```

Expected results (all possible combinations of all lengths combined into one row for each iteration):

```
Small,               P1        4  1.3   11
Small, Medium        P1,P2     6  2.9   15
Small, Medium,Large  P1,P2,P3  13 4.0   23
Medium               P2        2  1.6   4
Medium, Large        P2,P3     9  2.7   12
Large                P3        7  1.1   8
```

Edit:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

read_file = pd.read_excel (r'Data_list.xlsx')
read_file.to_csv ('Data_list.csv', index=True, header=True)
input_dict = read_file.to_dict('data_list')

output_dict = dict()
k = 0
for dict_size in range(1,len(input_dict)+1):
    for combination in itertools.combinations(input_dict, dict_size):
    d=len(combination) 
    k = k+1                                                                                     
    res[k] = input_dict[i]                                                                      
                                                                                            
    if d == 1:                                                                                  
    res[k] = {key: res[i][key] + input_dict[i].get(key, '') for key in res[i].keys()}
    else:                                                                                       
    res[k] = {key: res[i][key] + input_dict[1].get(key, '') for key in res[i].keys()}             

df = pd.DataFrame(res)             
df = df.T                          
print(df)                          
df.to_excel('Combined_data.xlsx')
```

Comment: You need to specify what library you are using to read and write Excel files as well the code for your own attempt using `itertools` (at least as far as you could take it).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In your expected results, you forgot `Small, Large`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question :)

Let's assume that you transform your excel into a CSV, which you read as a list of dicts (you can learn how to do this by reading the Python documentation)

You will need to use [itertools.combination](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) on `i` rounds (to have i-elements combinations), `i` going from 1 to the length of the initial list (included)

For each resulting list of combinations, you will have to perform your own transformation of elements (sum, string concatenation...)